# Adding drive "D" to a VMWare

Tags: hard-drive, vmware-workstation

I want my VMware workstation 6.5 to have a new hard drive named "D" ...
Ok,I can add a second hard drive but for its naming because the letter "D" is assigned to the CD-Drive, so it strarts naming from "E" ... I need it to be exactly "D" ...
what can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you're running in a Windows VM.

Windows has something called Disk Management, where you can assign the drive letters of each storage device. So you'll re-assign the CD-ROM to something like "F:", then move the second drive to "D:". Then move the CD-ROM back to "E:".

Get to Disk Management by right-clicking on `My Computer` and choosing `Manage`.